# java.lang.nullpointer exception in jmeter in Non-GUI mode

Tags: nullpointerexception, jmeter

When i try to execute my Jmeter (version 5.3) recorded script in Non-GUI mode, using a remote server, it displays a "java.lang.NullPointerException" while generating the dashboard(HTML) report. Also, my CSV file (or jtl report) is creating an empty file without any data.

I have used loop controller to call my http request .
I have added sample variables to my jmeter.properties file so that they can be recorded.
Also , I have set "jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv" in properties file.

[image]

The summarizer shows 0 and it shows error in generating report: java.lang.nullpointerexception.

Also, my log file shows the following:
[image]

Please let me know if there is any possible way to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: and where to get fullstack trace from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed jmeter and the same script worked well for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to generate [HTML reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from an **empty** [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

In its turn the .jtl results file is empty because no [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) were executed

And finally no samplers were executed because all your [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) are disabled

[image]

1. Open your .jmx script in JMeter GUI
2. Right click each Thread Group
3. Choose "Enable" from the context menu
4. Save the test plan

   [image]

If for some reason you cannot open JMeter GUI just change this line(s) in the .jmx file:

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="false">
```

to

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
```

with your favourite text editor or use [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool which can [change any property of any element in the runtime](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, my thread groups were enabled, probably there was some issue with the sample_varables, as it was giving me this issue with any .jmx file i tried to run. I re installed jmeter and the tests ran good.